# How to close dialog widget opened with `showDialog` on web browser back button pressed?

Tags: flutter, gorouter

I use `go_router` for page navigation in my web application (e.g /page1, /page2 etc). Navigation is executed via `context.go('/page1')`.

```dart
GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/page1',
      name: '/page1',
      pageBuilder: (context) {
        return WebPage(
          title: 'Page1',
          body: Page1(),
        );
      },
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/page2',
      name: '/page2',
      pageBuilder: (context) {
        return WebPage(
          title: 'Page2',
          body: Page2(),
        );
      },
    ),
    ...
  ],
)
```

```dart
class WebPage extends CustomTransitionPage {
  CustomTransitionPage(...) : super(child: WebScaffold(...));
}
```

To edit records which are displayed on widgets `Page1`, `Page2` etc I use `showDialog` in which the selected record is edited. For example, to edit items taken from `Page1` I call this:

```dart
final updatedItem = await showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => ItemEditDialog(item: item),
)
```

As you know `showDialog` uses `Navigator.of(context)` tu push modal route which is not related with navigator used by `go_router`.

*The problem*: Let's say user switched from route `/page1` to `/page2` and decided to edit an item selected in `Page2`. User clicks the edit button and the modal dialog (`ItemEditDialog`) becomes visible. Then user clicks the browser's *Back* button and we may notice that the previous state (previously visited route `page1`) becomes current one but *the edit dialog is still opened*. So the user sees the edit dialog (for editing items of `Page2`) over the items of `Page1` which is obviously confusing.

*The question*: How to close modal dialog widget when the user clicks `Back` button in web browser?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a _code example_

Comment: @MendelG code example gives nothing. I've updated description.

Comment: Well, without a _complete_ code example, it would be hard to help.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and easiest solution is to place some code inside `WebScaffold` class (actually state class `_WebScaffoldState`) which is the common scaffold for all web pages:

```dart
class WebScaffold extends StatefulWidget {
  ...
}

class _WebScaffoldState extends State<WebScaffold> {
  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant WebScaffold oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if(widget.title != oldWidget.title) {
      final navigator = Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true);
      if (navigator.canPop()) {
        navigator.pop();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As widgets used `showDialog` are shown in root navigator than it is enough to check if root navigator contains some route and if so just `pop` it.